# React auth component causes flickering

Tags: reactjs, react-router

When browsing between routes my react auth component causes flickering due to 2 pages requested. For example: user requests a new component called `StaffMeetingsPage`, react first runs the `AuthenticateComponent` then runs the `StaffMeetingsPage`. That causes flickering for me. Is there a way to fix it and make the auth code more reusable?

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import HomePage from './home/HomePage';
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import Login from "./home/Login";
import StaffMeetingsPage from "./StaffMeetings/StaffMeetingsPage";
import NotFound from "./NotFound";
import AuthenticateComponent from "./AuthenticateComponent";

const App = () => {
  return (
        <BrowserRouter >
          <div>
              <Route exact={true} path="/" component={HomePage}/>
              <Route exact={true} path="/login" component={Login}/>
              <AuthenticateComponent>
                  <Route exact={true} path="/meetings" component={StaffMeetingsPage}/>
              </AuthenticateComponent>
          </div>
        </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

export default App;
```

AuthenticateComponent.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { getJwt } from '../jwthelper.js';
import axios from 'axios';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

class AuthenticateComponent extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        user: undefined
    }
}

componentDidMount() {
    const jwt = getJwt();
    if (!jwt) {
        this.props.history.push('/login');
    } else {
        let axiosConfig = {
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
                'x-auth': jwt
            }
        };

        axios.get('/auth/me', axiosConfig).then((user) => {
            //Set users data to state
            this.setState({user: user.data});
        }).catch(res => {
            localStorage.removeItem('tkn');
            this.props.history.push('/login');
        });
    }
}

render() {
    if (this.state.user === undefined) {
        return <div>Loading user data...</div>;
    } else {
        return <div>{this.props.children}</div>;
    }
  };
};

export default withRouter(AuthenticateComponent);
```

StaffMeetingsPage.js

```
import React from 'react';

class StaffMeetingsPage extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        document.title = "Staff Meetings";
}

render() {
    return(
        <div>
            No meetings found...
        </div>
    );
  }
}

export default StaffMeetingsPage;
```

Answer (score 0):

try to

```
return null
```

instead of

```
<div>Loading user data...</div>
```